# Python: parse all links from some url

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, urllib

I need to parse all links from another url ( but I need to get only links, that have a common domain with domain, which I should parse).

I use

```
pages = set()
def get_links(url, page_url):
    global pages
    html = urlopen(url + page_url)
    page = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    for link in page.findAll("a", href=re.compile("^(/)")):
        if 'href' in link.attrs:
            if link.attrs['href'] not in pages:
                new_page = link.attrs['href']
                pages.add(new_page)
                try:
                   get_links(url, new_page)
                except:
                    continue
    return pages
```

But this code returns all links, that starts with `/`. How can I limit this to links, that belong to domain, what I parse?

Comment: Use a regex match for the domain on the link? This is pretty straightforward list filtering...

Comment: @JaredSmith links don't have a common pattern

Comment: Um, you just said they all belong to the same domain. That implies that they all share a common substring, which could be matched with regex. Its also unclear why you are checking for the existence of a thing before adding it to a set?

Comment: post a example url

Comment: @宏杰李 `omirussia.ru`

Comment: Please give several examples of the urls you want to match. Because its not really clear what you mean by "some are different".

Answer (score 1):

```
for a in soup('a', href=re.compile(r'^/ru/online_panels')):
    print(a['href'])
```

out:

```
/ru/online_panels/
/ru/online_panels/
/ru/online_panels/panel_quality/
```

the idea is same, put the string after the `^` will match all hrefs that starts with that string

Answer (score 0):

use the following regex for extracting the href:

```
domain = re.escape('mydomain.com')
regex = re.compile(r'(https?:\/\/)?(\w+\.)*%s(/[^\'"\s]+)?' % domain)
```

Comment: But that's not always looks like this. Sometimes it's just a continuation of path and it doesn't contain domain

Comment: can you provide an example? do you mean relative domain to the current domain like `<a href="/index.html" />`